# Starting an Activity from a Fragment causes the old Fragment onCreate to be called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, master-detail

So I have Activity A with Fragment A. The fragment contains a `LitView` which when an item is clicked, should start Activity B with Fragment B.

I am trying to user the Master-Detail flow, so eventually, when the user is using a tablet, Activity A will contain both, Fragment A and Fragment B.

Right now everything seems to be working ok, with the exception that once Activity B/Fragment B starts, Fragment A's onCreate method is called.

Could anyone try to help me understand why this is happening? And if you think I am making the wrong use of the Master-Detail Flow, or that there's a better way of implementing it, please, feel free to say so!

Here's my code:

**Activity A**

```
public class SearchResultsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG = "DFTAG";
private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results_list);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("query").toUpperCase());
    }

    if (findViewById(R.id.top_tracks_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the large-screen layouts
        // (res/layout-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the activity should be
        // in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.top_tracks_container, new TopTracksFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
    } else {
        mTwoPane = false;
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0f);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tracks_container, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Activity A' Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/include" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_artist_results"
    android:name="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.fragments.SearchResultsListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.fragments.SearchResultsListFragment"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

**Fragment A**

```
public class SearchResultsListFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String LOG_TAG = SearchResultsListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

//Spotify Variables
SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi();
SpotifyService spotifyService = spotifyApi.getService();
ListView albumsList;

private ProgressDialog ppDialog;

//Data variables
ArrayList<ArtistResults> mArtistResults;
String query;
private ArtistArrayAdapter adapter;

public SearchResultsListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    query = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("query");

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "savedInstanceState.containsKey(\"artistResults\"): " + savedInstanceState.containsKey("artistResults"));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "savedInstanceState.containsKey(\"query\"): " + savedInstanceState.containsKey("query"));
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("artistResults")) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "performSearch");
        ppDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        ppDialog.setMessage("Loading Albuns ....");
        mArtistResults = new ArrayList<>();
        performSearch(query);
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "saved artist");
        mArtistResults = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("artistResults");
    }
    adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter(getActivity(), mArtistResults);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_results_list, null);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    albumsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvAlbums);
    albumsList.setAdapter(adapter);

    albumsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ArtistResults album = adapter.getItem(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TopTracksActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("artistId", album.getArtistId());
            intent.putExtra("artistName", query.toUpperCase());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void performSearch(String query) {
    spotifyService.searchArtists(query, new Callback<ArtistsPager>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ArtistsPager artistsPager, retrofit.client.Response response) {
            List<Artist> listOfArtists = artistsPager.artists.items;

            if (listOfArtists.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ops, no albums found. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            for (Artist element : listOfArtists) {
                ArtistResults artistResults = new ArtistResults();
                artistResults.setName(element.name);
                artistResults.setArtistId(element.id);
                if (element.images.size() > 0) {
                    String url = element.images.get(0).url;
                    artistResults.setCoverImg(url);
                }
                mArtistResults.add(artistResults);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(ppDialog.isShowing()) {
                ppDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ops, no albums found. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Resume");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("artistResults", mArtistResults);
    outState.putString("query", query);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

**Fragment A's Layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.fragments.SearchResultsListFragment">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvAlbums"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

**Activity B**

```
public class TopTracksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_tracks);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Top Tracks");
        }

        TopTracksFragment fragment = new TopTracksFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_top_tracks, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Activity B's Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/top_tracks_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.activities.TopTracksActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/include" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_top_tracks"
    android:name="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.fragments.SearchResultsListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.spadatech.spotifystreamer.fragments.SearchResultsListFragment"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

**Fragment B**

```
public class TopTracksFragment extends Fragment {

//Layout Elements
private ListView tracksList;

//SPOTIFY related variables
private SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi();
private SpotifyService spotifyService = spotifyApi.getService();

//Data variables
private ArrayList<MyTracks> mTracks;
private String artistId;

//Others
private ProgressDialog ppDialog;
private TracksArrayAdapter adapter;
private boolean isOrientationChange = false;

public TopTracksFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //if(savedInstanceState == null) {

        artistId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("artistId");

        if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("tracks")) {
            mTracks = new ArrayList<MyTracks>();
            isOrientationChange = false;
        } else {
            mTracks = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("tracks");
            isOrientationChange = true;
        }

        adapter = new TracksArrayAdapter(getActivity(), mTracks);

        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("country", "US");

        if (!isOrientationChange) {
            ppDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            ppDialog.setMessage("Loading Tracks ....");
            populateList(artistId, options);
        }
    //}

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_tracks, container, false);

    tracksList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvTacks);
    tracksList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

private void populateList(String artistId, Map<String, Object> options){
    spotifyService.getArtistTopTrack(artistId, options, new Callback<Tracks>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Tracks tracks, Response response) {
            List<Track> listOfTracks = tracks.tracks;

            if (listOfTracks.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ops, no tracks found. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            for (Track item : listOfTracks) {
                MyTracks track = new MyTracks();
                track.setName(item.name);
                track.setAlbum(item.album.name);
                if (item.album.images.size() > 0) {
                    String url = item.album.images.get(0).url;
                    track.setCoverImg(url);
                }
                mTracks.add(track);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(ppDialog.isShowing()) {
                ppDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ops, no tracks found. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("tracks", mTracks);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

**Fragment B's Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvTacks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/include"/>
```